# HP OfficeJet 9025 Scan to Network Folder gives me "Incorrect Credentials" but OfficeJet 8600 works

Tags: network, scanning

I've had an HP OfficeJet 8600 for years with a Scan to Network Folder profile that will save the scanned file directly to a shared folder (shared as `Scans Local`) on my Mac. I just got a new HP OfficeJet 9020 series (9025e) and configured it the same way, but testing the Scan to Network Folder profile fails with "Incorrect Credentials".

8600 Configuration which works:

Network Path: `\\192.168.1.153\Scans Local`

Username: `kenny`

I have verified I'm using the same password on both.

Setting up the 9025, I created a new profile with the exact same configuration, but it just keeps saying:

`Incorrect credentials. Check your username/password and try again.`

The 8600, the 9025, and my Mac are all on the same 192.168.1.* network. I'm able to print to the 9025 from my Mac. I'm able to use the HP Smart app to tell the 9025 to scan the document on the glass and it sends it to the HP Smart app on my Mac and I can manually save it that way (i.e. I can talk to the printer and the printer can talk to me.)

I've even tried creating a new profile on the old 8600 with the same configuration just to make sure I had the right password. And the new profile, with all the same info, works just fine on the 8600.

What is different about the 9025? How can I get the 9025 working so that I can scan things directly to my Mac?

Any help is appreciated.

iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014)
macOS Big Sur 11.6

Screenshots of the configuration from the embedded web servers:

[image: OfficeJet 8600 configuration]

[image: OfficeJet 9025 configuration part 1]

[image: OfficeJet 9025 configuration part 2]

Comment: Have you tried a share name without spaces?

Comment: I haven't because the current share has been working for years and is still working with the old machine. If I get desperate tomorrow, I'll try setting up a new share, but each time I've done that it has been a whole new nightmare.

Comment: @KevinGrabher I set up a new shared folder called just `Scans` and I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, after days, weeks and months, this gave me the clue. For me GMT **was** needed, not local time. To be clear, I set the time and date to GMT, but the timezone ("Printer Country/Region Settings") to local.

For reference by other people and search engines, my logs were show the only slightly helpful but all too common:

> SMB client not supported - Unicode, NT Errors, Long Names and Extended Security are required

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342418)

Comment: Sorry, was that not clear? It was a correction to Kenny Wyland’s answer. He stated time should NOT be GMT. I was stating GMT time WAS necessary for me.

I could not comment on Kenny’s answer so I left my text in order to possibly help others in the future and hopefully save them the months of searching I endured. Just trying to be a helpful net citizen.

Comment: Same issue, same resolution. I have an "HP OfficeJet Pro 9010 series" printer/scanner. Had to manually set the printer time to UTC. There does not appear to be any option in the printer settings to indicate a particular timezone. After setting the printer to UTC, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I discovered that the [Scan to Network Folder documentation](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06696672) on the HP website is wrong.

In Step 2, they say that the printer's timezone must be set to GMT, but that is incorrect. It even explicitly says that setting it to my local timezone can cause it to fail... but the opposite was true. In order to get it to authenticate correctly, I had to set the time to my local timezone.

To do that using the Embedded Web Server, you click on the `Settings` tab, then `Date & Time` on the left side. Then click `Sync Now` which will synchronize the printer's timezone and time settings with the computer you're browsing from.

Then it worked.